# view my own HTML

Tags: 7.0-nougat

I have developed an HTML daylily data base with approximately 1700 pages of html code and daylily photos (over 1000 cultivars) over the past 6 years. I can read it on my PC, Laptop, old hipstreet titan tablet, but when I loaded it on my new Acer Iconia One 10" tablet, it refuses to display the data properly. It displays the home page but does access the CSS page. Nor can it find any of the linked pages. It still displays properly on my old Hipstreet Titan Tablet. I have downloaded and tried numerous browser apps with the same result.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get the web page displayed correctly by downloading and installing an HTML "edit and view" app called [Quoda](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.henrythompson.quoda). I have tried several and this will satisfy my requirements. It also allows me to edit pages and preview the changes.

Answer (score -1):

It's usually because Android doesn't have that level of access to the user storage, I have had this issue many times while trying to load websites from either internal storage or external storage.. After looking into I found that it's something to protect the user from running scripts like trying to load a website from a CD on a computer, it doesn't allow activeX content or whatever, The only solution I found was packaging the website as an application and allowing JavaScript in the WebView

It will work if built into an application as an asset for example, here's a snippet of an application that has database access, to load a website from android_asset
(the Assets folder inside an application)

```
WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wv);
  wv.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
  wv.getSettings().setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
  wv.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
  wv.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
  wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
  wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/HomePage-Or-Index.html");
```

Comment: I see that you corrected the issue I had with your answer, so I'll retract my downvote now.